# mIRC close window when fails to connect

Tags: mirc

I'm often connecting to multiple servers using `server -m` it opens new window for every server and I was wondering if it was possible to automatically close the window when it fails to connect. Possibly using the event `CONNECTFAIL`. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `close` command should do the trick

```
on *:connectfail: {
  ; -it: Inactive Status window (not connected nor connecting)
  close -it
}
```

More info here: http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/commands/close

Comment: awesome i tried this before not in the script window using `/close -i` but it didn't work but in the remote it works